# "Modified content" and "Untracked content"

Tags: github, terminal, visual-studio-code, commit

My question is about my folders being classified as `modified content` and `untracked content` when I use the Terminal on Mac to commit it to Github. I have used Visual Studio Code to edit/create all the files in the folders.

This is the message I get in Terminal when I try to commit the files:

```
    Changes not staged for commit:
modified:   *name of folder* (modified content, untracked content)
modified:   *name of folder* (modified content)
modified:   *name of folder* (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

What can I do to fix this? And what did I do to make the files modified/untracked?

Comment: What is your question? Git responds with `modified content` when a file is changed and `untracked content` when the file isn't covered by git's tracking.

Comment: My questions are in the initial post, but I can repeat them: What can I do to fix the issue with modified/untracked content, because it's not possible to commit these files to Github. And what did I do to make the files modified/untracked?

Comment: Ah. That is more clear. I will work on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a file in a git repository, by default, it isn't covered by the git tracking. You need to run `git add [FILEPATH]` to add it to the list of tracked files. Before you do this, any files like these will appear as `untracked`.

After this step is completed, the files will show up as being `modified` or `new file` depending on which platform you are using. Then you can commit the files with `git commit`.

Comment: I am kind of new to Github and the Terminal so excuse my ignorance,
 but 2 of the folders that I'm trying to upload are already tracked, even though I haven't used `git add [FILEPATH]` on them. And the files that I'm trying to upload to Github, weren't _created_ in the repository. They were created in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Even if they are tracked, still use `git add [FILEPATH]` before you `git commit -a` to commit the files. And yes, if you used VS Code to make the files in the same folder in the repo, then yes, they were *created* in the repo.